# ASP.NET Core 5.0 Sample Azure AD Auth Code Flow How to?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, active-directory

I use the most current project template for azure ad auth ASP.NET Core 5.0.
Its like:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

So, how do i enable Code Flow instead of implicit flow. I hardly get it...

Regards

Comment: Do you need a sample?

Comment: Would be very nice. I have used the template for ASP.NET Core. And now i realize, maybe it is already in code flow? I thought because it needs a tokenid, its implicit flow. But any flow needs to need the token... (For desktop / Web apps). So maybe its good already. What do you think?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: This is the sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/aspnetcore2-2-signInAndCallGraph